# views to display list and related content on same page

Tags: views, 7

I have created a veiws block which displays all the taxonomy terms of a particular type.
This block is in left sidebar . Now what I want is ,"when i click on any of the term all nodes related to it should be shown on the same page in the content area " ( what normally happens is it shows all nodes listing correctly but not on the content area of same page but takes me to next page) . Can someone please help me with this and any good tutorials for views

Comment: Are you using only views to show taxonomy term, if so then try enable the ajax.

Comment: i have used taxonomy module

Comment: I got it solved now

Comment: Better post your answer, It will help the future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved myself! What I did is:

1. Create a views page to display all contents having these taxonomy terms. This page has path "views-page".
2. Create a block view of those taxonomy terms, now while enabling this block the setting for pages tab is under Show block on specific pages --> select radio of "Only the listed pages" and the values for this should be :

   > views-page
   >   views-page/*

This way when you select a term all related posts appear on the page and taxonomy block is also there.